# jQuery show() hide() with nested levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I'm having a bit of an issue showing / hiding the next sublevel in a tree that I've generated. I think this scenario is different from the other questions posted here, and could use a bit of help. I can get the next levels to show, but clicking on the previous level to close the current level is proving tricky. I've tried all sorts of combinations of `parent()`, `next()`, `find()`, `closest()`, `is(':visible')`, and they all seem to interact with the other nodes on the tree - rather than the current one. For example, here's the display

```
Folder 1
   Folder 1 Subfolder
      Folder 1 subfolder level 2
Folder 2
   Subfolder 1
   Subfolder 2
      Subfolder 2 sublevel

<div class="subfolder">
<a  href="#">Folder 1</a>
 <div class="subfolder">
    <a  href="#">Folder 1 Subfolder</a>
    <div class="subfolder">
        <a  href="#">Folder 1 subfolder level 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="subfolder" title="This is the second folder">
<a href="#">Folder 2</a>
<div class="subfolder" title="">
    <a href="#">Subfolder 1</a>
</div>
<div class="subfolder" title="">
    <a href="#">Subfolder 2</a>
    <div class="subfolder">
        <a href="#">Subfolder 2 sublevel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To complicate things, I'm showing the first sublevels initially, using

```
//Show first sublevel folders for each parent
$subFolder.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.subfolder .subfolder').hide();

});
```

So, I can get the second level sublevels to show using

```
//show subfolders when parent is clicked, and hide details pane on any subfolder click
$subFolder.click(function () {
    $(this).children('div.subfolder').show();

});
```

But using `$(this).children('div.subfolder').hide();` obviously doesn't do the trick to hide them.

Basically, I'm looking for an interaction, that will hide both "Folder 1 Subfolder" and "folder 1 subfolder level 2" when Folder 1 is clicked. Is such a thing even possible using the above html structure?

Here's what I last ended up with that's in the ballpark, but still doesn't do the job

```
 $subFolder.click(function () {
    $(this).children('div.subfolder').show();
    if ($(this).find('.subfolder').is(':visible')) {
     $(this).find('.subfolder').stop().hide();
     }
     if ($(this).find('.subfolder').is(':hidden')) {
     $(this).next().find('.subfolder').stop().show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for? I changed some class names

```
$(".folder a").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.subfolder').slideToggle();
});

$(".subfolder a").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.innerfolder').slideToggle();
});
```

*****UPDATE***********

I used your original class names

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pmU33/3/)

Comment: unfortunately I can't change class names. that would make everything much easier. the structure is generated as described. thanks though

Comment: @apoji187 Ok I kept the classes the same and updated the fiddle